# Add comments to yaml generated using omegaconfig using rumael.yaml

Tags: python, yaml

I'm using omegaconfig to generate yaml configuration from python dataclasses but I've noticed that there's no way to add comments in the generated yaml file.

I'm looking for a way to take the generated yaml config string and add comments to different sections and values. I was thinking of using regex but I encountered a problem where I have a section followed by a subsection and I would have to be careful with the order I write the comments (my first initiative was to parse them from a class `__doc`` but now if I think better it's not a great idea and I think that doing so with rumael.yaml would be a better idea, but how?

From the obegaconfig documentation it's explained that generating the config from a dataclass works this way:

```
  from dataclasses import dataclass
>>> @dataclass
... class MyConfig:
...     port: int = 80
...     host: str = "localhost"
>>> # For strict typing purposes, prefer OmegaConf.structured() when creating structured configs
>>> conf = OmegaConf.structured(MyConfig)
>>> print(OmegaConf.to_yaml(conf))
port: 80
host: localhost
```

How can I inject into the generated yaml comments using rumael.yaml?

It would be nice if there was a way to parse the `__doc` on MyConfig class from:

```
"""
port: This is a comment
host: This is another comment
section.another: Commenting a value under a base section
"""
```

And have it automatically added in place in my yaml file so it would end something like:

```
port: 80 #this is a comment
host: localhost #this is another comment
section:
    another: #commenting a value under a base section
```